# How to Structure Modules in android Project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am in need that i need to group all the module in to single project(**app**)
Example :

```
- app
   |
   |- Module 1
   |
   |- Module 2
   |
   |- Module 3
```

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Comment: create new package for each module? I didn't really get it

Comment: @Shermano what i want is i need to  create a nested module, is it possible then how ?

Comment: @Stack Why? Try RKRK's solution and you won't have to nest them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**settings.gradle(Project Settings)**

```
include ':app', ':module1', 'module2'
```

And

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ....
    implementation project(path: ':module1')
    implementation project(path: ':module2')
}
```